# How do I get records proving that I was an Erasmus exchange student?

Tags: student-exchange

I was an Eramus interchange student in the UK for my final year project 20 years ago.

Whilst I have that in my CV, and even have in the Internet my final report in an old site of mine, I do not have a single proof in writing I was ever there. Even while there, I never had a proper student card, but just a provisory piece of paper.

Come to think of it, the most tangible documents I have ever with me even at the time where the check with the grant money and the programme evaluation form.

My tutor is probably retired. I recently emailed my project supervisor with this doubt, he did not answer.

Note that I myself work in Academia nowadays, and although it is in a different city and unrelated University, I might also pose them this doubt.

The document would come in handy someday, for instance to help me getting the nationality of my wife. What would be the best course of action for getting it after all this time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up contacting the Academic Services / Student Requests Information Team by email.

They said immediately they would provide a document, and they delivered; Pretty much professional and very attentive people.

They found my records from 20 years ago, but not my grades. Fortunately my dissertation grade is not so important, as I have it in another set of documents.

I already have the document in electronic form, and they also sent a paper copy.